# Openshift: server could not find the requested resource

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, kubernetes-helm

How on earth I'm getting this error message:

```
➜  ~ oc adm policy add-cluster-role-to-user cluster-admin -z tiller --namespace tiller
Error from server (NotFound): the server could not find the requested resource
```

So:

```
➜  ~ oc project
Using project "tiller" on server "https://192.168.99.100:8443".
➜  ~ oc get sa
NAME       SECRETS   AGE
builder    2         35m
default    2         35m
deployer   2         35m
tiller     2         30m
```

I don't quite figure out, why `tiller` service account is not found.

**EDIT**

```
➜  ~ oc version
oc v1.5.1+7b451fc
kubernetes v1.5.2+43a9be4
features: Basic-Auth GSSAPI Kerberos SPNEGO

Server https://master.si-origin-cluster.t-systems.es:8443
openshift v3.9.0+ba7faec-1
kubernetes v1.9.1+a0ce1bc657
```

Answer (score 0):

What is output of `oc version`?  Your client is likely not compatible with the server.

Comment: I've added `oc version` on post.

Comment: So if you get the ``oc`` client for OpenShift Origin 3.9, instead of that for 1.5 that you are using, does it work then? https://github.com/openshift/origin/releases/tag/v3.9.0

Comment: Your client is too old.  It is trying to access APIs that no longer exist.